Event not saving in calendar - react-native-calendar-events - React Native
I have the below code that creates an event and a button to fetch the events. This is based on using the package called react-native-calendar-events to save events.
I can create an event and fetch the events, the events is also showing correctly in the log/terminal when the button is clicked, but in the actual physical mobile calendar (google calendar) its not showing up why ? I am using physical device for debugging/dev.
    import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
    import {
      View,
      StyleSheet,
      TextInput,
      Button,
      Platform,
    } from 'react-native';
    import RNCalendarEvents from 'react-native-calendar-events';
    
    const SaveEventInfo = () => {
      const [eventTitle, setEventTitle] = useState('Hello world');
      const [eventLocation, setEventLocation] = useState('Global');
      const [eventId, setEventId] = useState('');
      const [calendars, setCalendars] = useState([]);
      const [pickedCal, setPickedCal] = useState(null);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        async function loadCalendars() {
          try {
            const perms = await RNCalendarEvents.requestPermissions();
            if (perms === 'authorized') {
              const allCalendars = await RNCalendarEvents.findCalendars();
              
              // Check for primary calendar
              const primaryCal = allCalendars.find(
                cal => cal.isPrimary && cal.allowsModifications,
              );
    
              console.log('All Calendars:', allCalendars);
              console.log('Primary Calendar:', primaryCal); 
              
              setCalendars(allCalendars);
              setPickedCal(primaryCal);
              console.log('Selected Calendar:', primaryCal); 
            } else {
              console.log('Calendar permission denied.');
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error while fetching calendars:', error);
          }
        }
    
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
          loadCalendars();
        }
      }, []);
    
      const createEvent = async () => {
        try {
          const startDate = new Date(); 
          const endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000); // 1 hour later
          
          const savedEventId = await RNCalendarEvents.saveEvent(eventTitle, {
            calendarId: Platform.OS === 'android' ? pickedCal?.id : undefined,
            startDate: startDate.toISOString(),
            endDate: endDate.toISOString(),
            location: eventLocation,
          });
      
          setEventId(savedEventId);
          alert('Event saved successfully.');
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Error while saving event:', error);
        }
      };
    
      const fetchEvent = async () => {
        try {
          const eventData = await RNCalendarEvents.findEventById(eventId);
          console.log('Event Data:', eventData);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Error while fetching event:', error);
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            placeholder="Enter Event Title"
            value={eventTitle}
            onChangeText={setEventTitle}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            placeholder="Enter Event Location"
            value={eventLocation}
            onChangeText={setEventLocation}
            multiline={true}
            numberOfLines={2}
          />
          <Button title="Save Event" onPress={createEvent} />
          <Button title="Fetch Event" onPress={fetchEvent} />
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    export default SaveEventInfo;
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: 16,
      },
      textInput: {
        height: 40,
        borderColor: 'gray',
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginBottom: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 8,
      },
    });

I also added the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>

but its not saving, how to make it save in the calendar ? What is missing here
